# What is the best way to boot my operating system from an external drive on a PC?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, bootable-media

My PC just crapped out on me, the motherboard has some bad capacitors so I purchased a new computer.  I was using windows 7, now I'm on windows 10.  My drive from the windows 7 computer is fine, operating system and all data.  What I want to do is boot into this drive, but my new computer doesn't have space for another drive, so I want to just buy an enclosure and boot into it that way.  Would that be possible?  The only other option is to remove the current drive, boot in, do whatever I need to do, and then replace the drive again.  But ideally, I'd like to just boot into it without removing the current drive.

Even more ideal would be to be able to boot into the windows external drive through my macbook, is that possible or do I need to install bootcamp?

Comment: Why? Data recovery? Is the old Windows 7 drive encrypted or something?

Comment: No its not encrypted, I want to view application settings and make a backup of my itunes library

Comment: Ok, so that is just basic data recovery. Copy music files, config files, etc. Just boot from the new working computer (Win10?), and don't even worry about trying to get this old orphaned Win7 hard drive to boot, plug it in (eSATA, SATA, USB...) and copy your wanted data.

Comment: But most of my wanted data is application settings.  For example, I want to have my iTunes settings and export playlists, just as they were, its easier if I can just look at the original and copy, instead of doing it all over again for every application.  Are there maybe some setting files that I can copy over from each application?  I would assume its different from each developer though...

Comment: Each program probably does have it's own settings stored in a separate file *somewhere*, maybe even in a registry (unfortunately not like linux with almost everything in your "home"). Some (guessing maybe iTunes?) may keep their settings online too, so just "logging in" with another computer may copy them. If you searched the web for where each program keeps it's settings that may help. But instead of trying to find & copy files, looking at the running programs and take screenshots or writing down the settings *may* even be less work... (Booting it in a VM is another idea)

Comment: Thats exactly what I want to do, but my drive doesn't boot so I can't look at the running programs, take screen shots or write anything down haha...  That would be ideal.  Right now I'm trying to figure out a way to do it per application, via app data cause I can't boot into the drive :(

Answer (score 1):

You can boot Windows from an external drive by setting the BIOS to enable booting from an external device.  Plug the external drive in, and when the computer starts, press the key to enter the BIOS (usually F10 or Del, sometimes F2, the screen should briefly show which button).  Navigate to your boot settings, enable booting from removable drive, and set the external hard drive to the 1st boot priority (If you can't seem to move it, highlight it and press + or -, seldom F5 and F6).  Press F10 to save and exit, then follow the on screen menu to boot from the external device.

I believe you would need bootcamp in order to select an external hard drive to run Windows, as the priority would usually rely on the internal Apple hard disk.  You can find more information for your system by running BootCamp Assistant on your MAC, if it's available.

Comment: are you sure I can boot from an external drive, according to Wes I can't...

Comment: Yes, I am sure.  There are some steps you may need to take in order to make your drive bootable however.

Comment: Wes's answer which categorically states you cannot boot from an external drive is false. I had a laptop whose internal drive failed and I was running it on Windows 7 from a USB. However the system you currently have installed would probably not work and fail during startup, you can give it a try, it could possibly work in safe mode from the USB.

Comment: I don't want to mess with the drive though, its already got a good OS on it plus all my data.  So in order to "make it bootable" you're basically asking me to install windows onto the drive, which would likely mean formatting the drive.  What I'm saying is that I have a drive, with windows, I want to boot into it somehow without installing it into the PC.  What is the best way to do that?

Comment: The best way is e-SATA, as I explained before.  The second best way would be via USB, if you want it externally.  Please be aware that as you've replaced the hardware, Windows is not configured for this new PC and will require new drivers, or may not boot at all without a system repair (option on the installation disk).

Comment: Thanks Raj, the main reason I want to boot into it is to see how I organized my applications and to view settings.  Would these be in tact after performing a system repair if it doesn't boot right away?

Comment: Yes they would.  A system repair would just address Windows files and folders, your appdata would be untouched.

Comment: I'm trying to boot externally with USB as my eSATA card is not working, however I'm not able to boot.  Its just bringing me to a blank screen, I have left it for over 15 minutes and its still blank.  You think it needs a system repair?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to go all through this and boot from external drive while you already have a system installed inside your internal hard drive. If is it just for the saved files, an external hard drive enclosure will be enough to convert your old drive into an accessible external drive that will help you access your files without a problem. I have done that many times.

But if you still want to boot from an external drive, then yes you can, as of Microsoft offered this feature in Windows 8 and up. While older versions will have to take alternative methods to make it possible. Also, It will also cause a data loss, meaning that you have to reformat the old drive to do a fresh install.
if you are still interested, you can check out [this article](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-run-a-portable-version-of-windows-from-a-usb-dri-1565509124).

Comment: The only real reason I want to boot into the old drive is to view the settings of applications and to make a backup of my iTunes library.  I don't think I can do these unless I boot in.

Comment: @GiH most of the applications settings will be saved as a file located within the application files or inside the registry. If you copy the applications folders from inside AppData folder then replace it with the current one that you have, then most of the app settings will be restored. Other Apps will store their settings inside the main app folder at (Program Files &  Program Files (x86) ).SO, you pick which one. Other than that, you might not be able to boot from the same OS external without having problems.

Comment: @GiH to reboot from the same system that you had the settings in it, You have to re-attache it back to your computer internally. As it was installed from the beginning. Save whatever you want to save inside the same drive just put it in different partition. after you're done, go back and return the new hard drive and put the old one inside an external enclosure. Then use the external drive as a regular external USB drive.

Comment: So, its not the actual files I'm interested in, those are all backed up already.  Its really just settings of my applications, and my iTunes playlists.  Where is the AppData folder located?  What are settings files stored as (xml?), so I can see if I can just locate and copy those over to the appropriate directories?

Comment: @GiH regarding the iTunes, just copy the iTunes folder that is located inside the My Music folder, and then install iTunes. After installation is finished, open iTunes for the first time and follow the instructions, (don't search for media), this will make the iTunes create iTunes folders. Now, close the iTunes, and go to My Music folder, replace the new iTunes iTunes folder with the one you copied from the old drive. Then re-lunch iTunes, and your settings, playlists, music, all library will be there.

Comment: @GiH regarding the AppData, it's located inside C:\Users\<userFolder>\AppData. It's hidden by default, you have to change the folders options to show the hidden files in order to see it.

Comment: HUGE THANKS for the iTunes recommendation, it worked!  I did create another question for that as you saw, please put the answer there and I'll accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot take a Win7 boot drive, place it into an enclosure, and boot it on a different computer (or even the same computer).  Windows 7 does not support being booted from external media... at all... even if it's a Mac.

The ONLY exception to this rule is eSATA. You CAN boot an external eSATA drive because Win7 does not usually see eSATA drives as removable. However, finding a computer with an eSATA port is rare these days.

Comment: good thing I have an eSATA card!  I'll get a eSata enclosure then

Comment: As long as the eSATA card uses a common chipset (i.e. doesn't require a driver).

Comment: There are numerous websites and youtube videos with instructions on how to install windows to removable media.  I personally have a 64GB USB 3.0 flash drive with Windows 7 Ultimate installed on it.  EDIT:  It's actually 64GB.  e-SATA is preferable though, so go ahead and use that if you can find an enclosure with it.

Comment: @WesSayeed How can I tell if the card uses a common chipset? What am I looking for?

Comment: I've seen these videos too and have even done it myself. But they are hacks. Win7 Embedded has USB/SD Card boot support built-in, but MS does not include those drivers on retail editions. Most of these hacks involve copying the USB drivers from Win7 Embedded and making the necessary registry changes.

Comment: As long as the card is supported natively by Windows 7 it should work. Look at the biggest chip on the card.  If it says Marvell or Silicon Image you're probably fine. But there are some Promise, HighPoint, LaCie, Sonnet, NewerTech, etc. cards that require you to load a driver for them to work. Windows 7 does not support those natively.  Also, if the card has any kind of RAID functionality, it probably won't work either.

Comment: This is my card http://www.firmtek.com/seritek/seritek-2se2-e/, and this is my PC http://www.amazon.com/Lenovo-ideacentre-300-20ISH-Desktop-i7-6700/dp/B0195XZ70A/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1459312113&sr=8-1&keywords=300-20ish

Comment: The card says Silicon Image on the mid chip, the largest one says PMC

Comment: That will probably work. Let's hope it doesn't need to do a HW detection on a live system for it :-)

Comment: Wes's comments are better than the original answer.  He's absolutely correct in the comments.  It is not a difficult task however GiH, and if your e-SATA card fails then please copy the boot files as instructed (google) to use your external via USB.  It should, however, work perfectly via e-SATA, so long as you install the Windows drivers (comment below)

Comment: Windows 7 does support booting from external drives.

Comment: [Citation Needed]

Comment: No luck with the eSATA :(.  It didn't ask me for drivers, maybe its not compatible with this mobo.  It plugged in fine but it won't get recognized, doesn't even show up as a hardware change.  So I can't boot in, tried via USB and tried plugging it in internally, neither worked.

Comment: @RajHuff I'm not sure what you mean by "if your e-SATA card fails then please copy the boot files as instructed (google) to use your external via USB".  Copy what boot files?  From where to where?

Comment: In your case that's a next-step problem.  Are you using power over e-SATA?  Is your hard drives' power cable plugged in?  Your hard drive is not detected via USB?  Not even as an un-formatted  device?  Or are you saying that Windows detects it, but you cannot boot from it?

Comment: Its working with USB as storage, but it won't boot as you guys predicted.  The eSATA is not working at all, I think the card I have might not be working anymore.  Honestly I'm thinking the best thing for me to do here is run it as a virtual machine.  Is that possible without being able to boot into it first?